# JSON Javascript quiz game

Tags: javascript, json, html

I'm developing a bird quiz in html5 using javascript and json. The user has to identify the bird by clicking the right picture.To reward the user, a youtube video of the given bird is automatically played. My problem here is that, the right video is not being played so for example even though the right answer for question one is a parrot, a video of a Quetzal is played. I want the right video to be played by the right question.

This is my json content.

```
{
  "quizlist":[
  {
    "question":"Which picture shows a Parrot?",
    "option1":"Parrot.png",
    "option2":"Cardinal.png",
    "option3":"Toucan.png",
    "option4":"Owl.png",
    "videoURL" : "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RfXxh0Eff_w"
    },
  {
    "question":"Which picture shows a Peacock?",
    "option1":"Peacock.png",
    "option2":"Flamingo.png",
    "option3":"Quetzal.png",
    "option4":"Penguin.png",
    "videoURL" : "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jz-tjJhFH1k"
    },
    {
      "question":"Which picture shows a Cockatoo?",
      "option1":"Cockatoo.png",
      "option2":"Turkey.png",
      "option3":"Duck.png",
      "option4":"Penguin.png",
      "videoURL" : "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TTb77syQjMg"
    },
  {
    "question":"Which picture shows a Toucan?",
    "option1":"Toucan.png",
    "option2":"Falcon.png",
    "option3":"Hummingbird.png",
    "option4":"Penguin.png",
    "videoURL" : "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WAYntcQTm5A"
    },
    {
      "question":"Which picture shows a Quetzal?",
      "option1":"Quetzal.png",
      "option2":"Cardinal.png",
      "option3":"Flamingo.png",
      "option4":"Owl.png",
      "videoURL" : "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IhSCnjr3-MY"
    }
  ]
}
```

And this is my javascript code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var questionNumber=0;
    var questionBank=new Array();
    var stage="#game1";
    var stage2=new Object;
    var questionLock=false;
    var numberOfQuestions;
    var score=0;
    var vidURL;


    $.getJSON('js/activity.json', function(data) {
        console.log(data);

        for(i=0;i<data.quizlist.length;i++){
            questionBank[i] = new Array;
            questionBank[i][0] = data.quizlist[i].question;
            questionBank[i][1] = data.quizlist[i].option1;
            questionBank[i][2] = data.quizlist[i].option2;
            questionBank[i][3] = data.quizlist[i].option3;
            questionBank[i][4] = data.quizlist[i].option4;
            //questionBank[i][5] = data.quizlist[i].videoURL;
            vidURL = data.quizlist[i].videoURL;
            console.log(vidURL);
        }

        numberOfQuestions=questionBank.length;

        displayQuestion();
        console.log('Display Questions Ran');
    })//gtjson

    function displayQuestion(){
        var rnd = Math.random()*4;
        rnd = Math.ceil(rnd);
        var q1;
        var q2;
        var q3;
        var q4;


        if(rnd==1){q1=questionBank[questionNumber][1]; q2=questionBank[questionNumber][2]; q3=questionBank[questionNumber][3]; q4=questionBank[questionNumber][4];}
        if(rnd==2){q2=questionBank[questionNumber][1]; q3=questionBank[questionNumber][2]; q4=questionBank[questionNumber][3]; q1=questionBank[questionNumber][4];}
        if(rnd==3){q3=questionBank[questionNumber][1]; q4=questionBank[questionNumber][2]; q1=questionBank[questionNumber][3]; q2=questionBank[questionNumber][4];}
        if(rnd==4){q4=questionBank[questionNumber][1]; q1=questionBank[questionNumber][2]; q2=questionBank[questionNumber][3]; q3=questionBank[questionNumber][4];}



        $(stage).append(
            '<ul class="collection"> <li class="collection-item active black">' + questionBank[questionNumber][0] + '</li></ul>' +
            '<hr style="margin-bottom: 20px">' +
            '<div id="1" class="col s6 pix"><img src="img/'+q1+'" width="30%"></div>' +
            '<div id="2" class="col s6 pix"><img src="img/'+q2+'" width="30%"></div>' +
            '<div id="3" class="col s6 pix"><img src="img/'+q3+'" width="30%"></div>' +
            '<div id="4" class="col s6 pix"><img src="img/'+q4+'" width="30%"></div>'
        );

        $('.pix').click(function(){
            if(questionLock==false){questionLock=true;
                //correct answer
                if(this.id==rnd){

                    var $toastContent = $('<span>Correct</span>');
                    var myMedia = new Media("http://soundbible.com/grab.php?id=1974&type=mp3")
                    myMedia.play()

                    Materialize.toast($toastContent, 6000);
                        window.open(vidURL, '_system');

                    score++;
                }
                //wrong answer
                if(this.id!=rnd){

                    var $toastContent = $('<div class="center-align"><span>Wrong</span></div>');
                    var myMedia = new Media("http://soundbible.com/grab.php?id=1495&type=mp3")
                    myMedia.play()
                    Materialize.toast($toastContent, 2000);

                }
                setTimeout(function(){changeQuestion()},3000);
            }})
    }//display question


    function changeQuestion(){

        questionNumber++;

        if(stage=="#game1"){stage2="#game1";stage="#game2";}
        else{stage2="#game2";stage="#game1";}

        if(questionNumber<numberOfQuestions){displayQuestion();}else{displayFinalSlide();}

        Materialize.fadeInImage(stage2);
        $(stage2).empty();
        Materialize.fadeInImage(stage);
        $(stage).animate({"right": "+=800px"},"slow", function() {questionLock=false;});
    }//change question

    function displayFinalSlide(){

        $(stage).append('<div class="questionText">You have finished the quiz!<br><br>Total questions: '+numberOfQuestions+'<br>Correct answers: '+score+'</div>');

    }//display final slide

});
```

Comment: Instead of using `new Array`, use `[]`. Change `new Object` to `{}`

Comment: the problem still persists. It still only opens the video link of quetzal.

Comment: It would be helpful if you wrote that you used phonegap/cordova - or better if you removed the `new Media` and `Materialize.toast` stuff

Comment: @kodecount thanks but that didn't solve the problem.

Comment: @gus27 thanks for the tip. I'm however using new Media to play a bird sound once the right answer is chosen so i really need that.

Comment: I'm sure you need it for your production code. But here you should make it others as easy as possible to grasp your problem by providing a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @gus thanks. I'll bear that in mind. Is there a reason i can't play the audio files locally stored in the www folder? the program seems not to find it even though the files are available in the folder. it however plays files from external sources.

Comment: Yeah it just a different approach is all: https://jsfiddle.net/kpduncan/p4q8hxyz/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You open the video by `window.open(vidURL, '_system');` but the global `vidURL` variable is initialized in the `for` loop of `getJSON`. So it always contains the last value of the `data.quizlist[i].videoURL` - which will always be the URL of the Quetzal video.

Here's one way on how to make this work:

```
[...]
var vidURL;
var videoBank = [];
$.getJSON(...) {
   [...]
   for(i=0;i<data.quizlist.length;i++){
       [...]
       videoBank[i] = data.quizlist[i].videoURL;
   }
   [...]
}
function displayQuestion(){
   [...]
   var vidURL = videoBank[questionNumber];
   [...]
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This indeed solved my problem. That line of code you added to the displayQuestioin function is what solved the entire problem.